# Polymode in org-edit-special

Tags: org-babel, python, hooks, syntax-highlighting, polymode

I use `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'poly-python-sql-mode)` where `poly-python-sql-mode` is a special `polymode` that correctly highlights SQL queries that are used within strings in a Python file.

When this is used, and I use `org-edit-special` on a Python block there is no host-mode syntax highlighting in the Python buffer. Only the inner-modes have syntax highlighting. So the SQL is highlighted, but the Python is not.